# How to create group clause in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, clause, linq-group

I am trying to query 2 tables, `Club` and `LinkClubUser`. I want to retrieve the last club that a User is assigned from the last Date in the LinkclubUser.

I have the right SQL query:

```
select top 1 
    max(A.DataInscricao), 
    A.Nome, A.NomeNaCamisola, A.NumNaCamisola, A.Posicao, A.Situacao  
from 
    Clube as A 
inner join 
    LinkClubeUser as B on a.Id = b.IdClube
where 
    b.IdUser ='9faea9f3-28d7-4e34-8572-3102726d3c75'
group by 
    A.Nome, A.NomeNaCamisola, A.NumNaCamisola, A.Posicao, A.Situacao
```

I got the right row.

I try to convert this query to Entity Framework Core like this, but I get back more than 1 row:

```
var query = _dbContext
                .LinkClubeUser
                .Join(_dbContext.Clube,
                    lnk => lnk.IdClube,
                    clube => clube.Id,
                    (Lnk, clube) => new { Lnk, clube })
                .Where(t => t.Lnk.IdUser == "9faea9f3-28d7-4e34-8572-3102726d3c75")
                .GroupBy(t => new
                {
                    t.clube.Id,
                    t.clube.Nome,
                    t.clube.NomeNaCamisola,
                    t.clube.NumNaCamisola,
                    t.clube.Posicao,
                    t.clube.Situacao,
                    t.clube.DataInscricao
                }, t => t.clube)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    Nome = g.Key.Nome,
                    NomeNaCamisola = g.Key.NomeNaCamisola,
                    NumNaCamisola = g.Key.NumNaCamisola,
                    Posicao = g.Key.Posicao,
                    Situacao = g.Key.Situacao,
                    DataInscricao = (DateTime)g.Max(p => p.DataInscricao)
                }).Take(1);
```

but this code is converted by Entity Framework Core like this

```
SELECT 
    [lnk].[Id], [lnk].[Date], [lnk].[IdClub],
    [lnk].[IdQuestionario], [lnk].[IdUser], [clube].[Id],
    [clube].[ClubActual], [clube].[Date], [clube].[Nome],
    [clube].[NomeNaCamisola], [clube].[NumNaCamisola], [clube].[Posicao],
    [clube].[Situacao]
FROM 
    [LinkClubeUser] AS [lnk] 
INNER JOIN 
    [Clube] AS [clube] ON [lnk].[IdClube] = [clube].[Id]
WHERE 
    [lnk].[IdUser] = N'9faea9f3-28d7-4e34-8572-3102726d3c75' 
ORDER BY 
    [clube].[Id], [clube].[Nome], [clube].[NomeNaCamisola],
    [clube].[NumNaCamisola], [clube].[Posicao], [clube].[Situacao],
    [clube].[DataInscricao]
```

I don't see the group by clause.

What's wrong in my Entity Framework Core query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don´t have the group clause.

I think you added all the `clube` table fields to your group clause so your group clause lost its nature and did not compile to SQL, while you added some of them in your first SQL query.

**Edit**

```
var query = (from user in _dbContext.LinkClubeUser
             Join club in _dbContext.Clube on user.IdClub equals club.Id into cu
             let clubUser = cu.DefaultIfEmpty() // outer join if you need it
                Where clubUser.IdUser == "9faea9f3-28d7-4e34-8572-3102726d3c75")
                Select  new
                {
                    Nome = user.Nome,
                    NomeNaCamisola = user.NomeNaCamisola,
                    NumNaCamisola = user.NumNaCamisola,
                    Posicao = user.Posicao,
                    Situacao = user.Situacao,
                    DataInscricao = (DateTime)clubUser.Max(p => p.DataInscricao)
                }).Take(1);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Ryan, If I try to remove some clube fields in the groupby, I loose those, field in anonymous in the select below. Example If I remove the t.clube.Nome, I loose the Nome = g.Key.Nome,

Comment: Hello jolynice, which fields you want to group on? I will update my answer depends on them

Comment: Hello Ryan, thanks for your help, In fact I only need this fields 
                    t.clube.Nome,
                    t.clube.NomeNaCamisola,
                    t.clube.NumNaCamisola,
                    t.clube.Posicao,
                    t.clube.Situacao,,

Comment: Thanks Ryan is working, now I need to understand lol. Many Thanks